# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar solo un campo usando procedimientos almacenados con parámetros?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create procedure sp_actualizardato 

@EmpNo int,
@Apellido varchar(50)  ,
@oficio varchar(50) ,
@dir int,
@fecha smalldatetime,
@salario numeric(9,2),
@comision numeric(9,2),
@dept_no    int
as

update    Emp set
apellido=@Apellido ,
Oficio=@oficio,
Dir=@dir ,
Fecha_Alt=@fecha ,
Salario=@salario ,
Comision=@comision ,
Dept_No=@dept_no
where Emp_No=@EmpNo
```

solo quiero actualizar digamos que el oficio pero que los demás datos se conserven.

Answer (score 1):

Si no entendí mal, quieres que el SP actualice los datos de una tabla en función de los parámetros que se le pasan, voy a explicarlo con solo dos de los campos que tienes: `@Apellido` y `@oficio`, para hacer más sencilla la idea:

Buscarías poder hacer algo como esto:

```
-- Para actualizar solo el apellido y no el resto de los datos
EXEC sp_actualizardato @EmpNo = 1, @Apellido = 'Apellido nuevo'

-- Para actualizar solo el oficio y no el resto de los datos
EXEC sp_actualizardato @EmpNo = 1, @oficio = 'Oficio nuevo'
```

Para hacer esto, en primer lugar debemos definir un valor "default" para cada parámetro, este valor es muy importante y hay que elegirlo con cuidado, sera un valor que no sea posible que sea necesario en ninguna de la columnas. Este valor tendrá un significado especial, le dirá al SP que NO queremos modificar el valor de la columna correspondiente. Para este ejemplo, ya que tanto `@Apellido` como `@oficio` son valores del tipo caracter, voy a definir el valor default como `N/A`, cuando no pasemos ninguno de estos parámetros, el valor por defecto será `N/A`, con este valor lo que debieramos hacer a la hora de actualizar es no actualizar el campo o más bien actualizarlo pero con el mismo valor. El ejemplo seria algo así:

```
create procedure sp_actualizardato 
                 @EmpNo int,
                 @Apellido varchar(50) = 'N/A',
                 @oficio varchar(50) = 'N/A'
as

update Emp 
       set apellido = case when @Apellido = 'N/A' then apellido else @Apellido end,
           Oficio   = case when @oficio = 'N/A' then Oficio else @oficio end
       where Emp_No=@EmpNo
```

Esto lo que nos permite es que si hacemos:

```
EXEC sp_actualizardato @EmpNo = 1, @Apellido = 'Apellido nuevo'
```

`@oficio` valdrá `N/A` y `@Apellido` será `'Apellido nuevo'`, si ves la sentencia de `UPDATE`, veras que `Apellido` se actualizará con el nuevo valor y `Oficio` será actualizado con el mismo que ya tiene.

#### Importante

Esta solución es un truco y puede tener efectos no deseados, ten en cuenta que si la tabla tiene triggers que se disparan al efectuarse la actualización de un campo, funcionarán en cualquier caso aunque la columna la actualices con el mismo valor. Otra alternativa que podrías investigar, que puede ser más precisa es la de construir dinámicamente la sentencia de `UPDATE`

Comment: Seguí los pasos que indico Patricio Moracho, para mi caso lo único que agregue fue una variable auxiliar para obtener el contenido actual de ese campo y así no perder esa información (línea 16 y 17 en la imagen). En el update al momento de asignar el contenido al campo obs_trn de la tabla turno se evalúa que el parámetro `@observacion` contenga su valor asignado por defecto (línea 4), si es así entonces se asigna el contenido de la variable `@obserbacionAux` (para no perder la información contenida), volvemos a evaluar que la variable `@obserbacion` ahora sea diferente <> de '-' que es el valo